# CMD command to install sql server 2005 express edition via command prompt (silent install)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How to install sql server 2005 express edition via command prompt (silent install). Further the installed instance should be accessible via lan

instance name: test
username : sa
password : admin123

Can you plz generate the required script for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is my script: 
  start /wait C:\SQLSERVER2005\SQLEXPR32.EXE /qb username="CustomerUsername" companyname="OurCompany" addlocal=ALL  disablenetworkprotocols="0" instancename="MSSQLSERVER" SECURITYMODE="SQL" SAPWD="cyborg"      
But when I connect it using cmd it does not connect

Answer (score 0):

Script can be found here:

[How to: Install SQL Server 2005 from the Command Prompt](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259(SQL.90).aspx)

```
Start /wait <CD or DVD Drive>\servers\setup.exe /qb INSTANCENAME=<InstanceName> 
ADDLOCAL=All PIDKEY=<pidkey value with no "-"> SAPWD=<StrongPassword> 
SQLACCOUNT=<domain\user> SQLPASSWORD=<DomainUserPassword> AGTACCOUNT=<domain\user> 
AGTPASSWORD=<DomainUserPassword> SQLBROWSERACCOUNT=<domain\user> 
SQLBROWSERPASSWORD=<DomainUserPassword>
```

Comment: well this is the documentation from msdn... but frankly this is not working ! The instance cannot be accessed... have u tried this yourself?

Comment: I have not tried it.. but since its from Microsoft this should work.
What instance name did you provide?.